# How to get alternating characters from a string in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, character

I am working on a script in which I have to read alternating characters from a string.

I am using the following approach:

```
$s = "abcdef"
$chars = $s.ToCharArray()
For( $i = 0; $i -lt $chars.Count; $i = $i + 2){
    $chars[$i]
}
```

Is there a simpler approach, especially one based on a pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a simple regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/rL1lC4/1)) to match two characters and replace it with the first one:

```
 $s -replace '(.).', '$1'
```

*Output*:

```
ace
```

If you want to have characters, just cast it to an `char[]`:

```
[char[]] ($s -replace '(.).', '$1')
```

or *split* the string (thanks PetSerAl):

```
$s -replace '(.).', '$1' -split '(?!^|$)'
```

Comment: here finally u r forming a string only. What if we want to retrieve characters?

Comment: I updated my answer how you can retrieve characters. I also added a regex demo. Basically, I capture the first character and replace the first two characters with the captured one.

Comment: `-split ''` -> `-split '(?!^|$)'` to not produce two empty strings.

Comment: ++, but I suggest removing the `-split` alternative, because it is mostly a distraction.
If you want to show an alternative to casting to `[char[]]`, I suggest `($s -replace '(.).', '$1').ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 3):

Love the regex answer but wanted to include something that used the pipeline more and `Select-Object`

```
$string = "abcdef" 
[char[]]$string | Select-Object -Index (0..($string.Length-1) | Where-Object{$_ % 2})
```

`-Index` takes the length of the string and returns and array of odd numbers used to extract the characters from the char array. Using `!($_ % 2)` would alternate the returned set. In both cases I am taking advantage of the value returned by the modulus operator. If the number is even in the above example 0 is returned which evaluates to false. `$_ % 2 -eq $false` would accomplish the same thing and be more readable depending.

Comment: Nice Matt. I also tried to solve this using pipeline and array arithmetic but got stuck (I missed Where-Object).

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
$string = 'abcdefg'
$i=0
([char[]]$string).where({$i++ %2})
b
d
f
```

Comment: ++; note to future readers: this _method_ syntax - a faster and more flexible alternative to the `Where-Object` _cmdlet_ - requires PSv4+. You can read more [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/).

Comment: One more way... Thanks @mklement0   :)

Comment: @Rushikesh: Thanks, but credit goes to this answer's author, mjolinor - I merely provided _supplemental_ information.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's simpler, but it's different:

```
$s = "abcdef"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $s.Length; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 2 -ne 0)
    {
        $s[$i]
    }
}
```